# What is a good resource to learn how to build chords from scales?

Tags: guitar, learning, chords

I would like to understand how chords are made (like G/F# or Bb etc.) so I can figure out what a chord is by remembering the scale.

Is there a good resource for learning this? If I want to learn how to do this, is it recommended that I learn all of the scales first (Blues, Major, Minor, Pentatonic etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst leaning all the scales will be of great help in your playing, and probably understanding, the main one for this purpose is the major scale. Chords basically are made up of 1-3-5 of a scale. These are triads- 3 notes. Using the major scale, these will be major chords. To get minors, you could just make the maj. 3rd into a min. 3rd, rather than use the minor scale - the end product is the same.

Chords with numbers - C7, C9 etc. will use the extra number note of that scale as well, although various rules need to be brought into play as well.Slash chords will be the basic chord from the first letter name, with the second letter name as the lowest note played, sometimes as an extra note to the chord.

There have been numerous questions pertaining to this and related questions on this site, so not going into more depth right now.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t begin with pentatonic or blues scales. The best help to understand the chords is a keyboard as it represents much better the western tone system than any other instrument. A virtual keyboard on a phone or tablet will fit!

1. Start by playing (and singing) the intervals of 3 rds on the white keys of a piano. Write them down in the folloing ways: as schema of the keyboard, as sheet music, by arabic numbers, by roman numbers and by the names of abc and doremi.
2. play (and sing) all the triads of the C major scale and note them on a sheet as described above.
   Don‘t forget to sing them or image wth you inner ear pitch (as well as their whole affect) while notsting by pencil and paper.
3. continue with 7 by adding another 3rd tonthe  trads of C major scale and study they in the same way as the intervals of 3rd and triads, playing, singing, writing in the above described ways of abstraction.

(later you may continue with the 79 11 and 13 chords)

but now is the point to transfer your knowledge about the triads  on your guitar: find out the chord scheme, the tab, play and notate in a staff.

From here you will be able to elaborate and develop  yourself the same chords in all scales (in the circle of fifths)